# How to call a result that inside a list in model?

Tags: flutter, dart, model

here's a model that i want to call https://wtools.io/paste-code/bH4E

but i don't know how to print or call the result that being inside the response with streambuilder, do you know how to call it? because when i try to call it, it always show the error code, i have try few way to calling it but it really doesn't work, here's the streambuild example:

```
       StreamBuilder<dynamic>(
          stream: _leavelistbloc.mkiDataStream,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              switch (snapshot.data!.status!) {
                case Status.INITIAL:
                  return Text('initial');
                case Status.LOADING:
                  return Text('loading');
                case Status.COMPLETED:
                  return Text("i want to call the result inside this");
                case Status.ERROR:
                  return Text('error');
              }
            }
            return Container();
          },
        ),
```

Comment: could you include mkiDataStream?

Comment: mkiDataStream is inside Bloc, you can see it on here https://wtools.io/paste-code/bH6K